# Create Visual Studio "add-on" that copies file to output directory

Tags: visual-studio, plugins

Is it possible to create an add-on that allows you to copy a file to the output directory?  I have a group of XML files that I use for configuration.  I modify these files often while debugging, but they don't get copied over when I start debugging or build because they don't actually affect the source code files.  This is the case even if "Copy to Output Directory" is set to "always" for that particular file.

I'd like to be able to simply right click the XML file I modified and choose a "copy to output dir" option.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a post-build event which consists of a command that will copy these files to the output directory. In a VB.NET project you can find this option under "Project settings" -> "Compile" -> "Build events". Then you type in "Post-build event command line" a command like
 `copy .\source\file .\destination`. Have also a look at the existing macros.

Comment: The problem with post-build events is that they don't get triggered when I just modify an XML file; they get triggered when a source file requires the project to be re-compiled, hence the reason I need another solution.